# How can I get squared buttons in a flex layout with CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox

I think flex is a good solution to develop a responsive video player control bar. The example is the control bar of the amazon player.

On the left and right I want squared buttons. The progress bar gets the rest of the space.

I thought about setting padding-top equal to height but it is not working.

What is wrong?

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="image/svg+xml"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compartible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Video Player flex</title>

    <style>
    html {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        }

    body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        border: 0px;
        }

    .pic {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .pic img {
       object-fit: contain;
    }

    .control-bar {
        display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
        display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
        display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
        display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
        display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */


        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
    }

    .pause_btn {
        flex-grow:1;
        background-color: DD88EE;
        background-image: url(media/pause-icon-white-48.svg);
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        min-height: 40px;
        min-width: 40px;            
    }

    .time {
        flex-grow:1;
        background-color: #CB8C1D;
        min-height: 40px;
        min-width: 40px;
    }

    .fullscreen_btn {
        flex-grow:1;        
        background-color: #4C3327;
        background-image: url(media/fullscreen-icon-off-white-48_160.svg);
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
    }

    .sound_btn {
        flex-grow:1;
        background-color: #BD3632;
        background-image: url(media/speaker_loud_white_48.svg);
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;            
    }

    .progress {
        flex-basis:50%;
        flex-grow:1;        
        background-color: #4C3327;
        min-height: 40px;
        min-width: 40px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 769px) {
        .duration{
            flex-grow:1;
            background-color: #CB8CEE;
            min-height: 40px;
            min-width: 40px;
        }
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color:black; text-align: center;">

    <div class="pic">
        <img src="media/vorschaubild.png" alt="Smiley face" height="100%" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="">
        <div class="control-bar-wrapper">
            <div class="control-bar">
                <div class="pause_btn">pause</div>
                <div class="time">time</div>
                <div class="duration"></div>
                <div class="progress">progress</div>    
                <div class="sound_btn">sound</div>
                <div class="fullscreen_btn">full</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to have the height and width of the bottom as a ratio of the page width, you have to use a wrapper for the buttons:

```
    .square {
      width: 10%; // Width = 10% of page with
    }

    .square div {
      padding-bottom: 100%; // So height = 10% of page width
      line-height: 0px;     // Avoid additional height
    }
```

And the button elements wrapped like this:

```
    <div class="square">
       <div class="pause_btn"></div>
    </div>
```

Also, the `padding-bottom` technique implies that the elements don't contain any non-absolute elements (which otherwise add to the height of the element, breaking its squareness)

That's why I removed captions and set `line-height` to 0

**Here is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/jsfmb9at/3/**

*Edit: I removed `flex-grow: 1` from these non-expanding elements, and added a `max-width` to the `.square` css, otherwise the control bar is too big on horizontal players, which is weird...*

**Other solutions :**

- For buttons which width is a ratio of page height, the easiest way would be to just set `control-bar` height as a percentage of height, and square `<img>` elements as buttons (I see you use images, as background) and setting their wrapper as 'display: inline-block'
- To get rid of images or image requests, you can even use `<img>` elements with transparent images data provided inline with a `data:` URI with the required ratio (1:1 for square)

Comment: Your first solution is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Would you consider upvoting / checking it as the accepted answer? Thanks!